# Simple form of gradient by parameter?

Tags: derivatives, optimization

I have an optimization problem $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{a})≈0$, where $\mathbf{x}:\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbf{a}:\mathbb{R}^4, \mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}^4$. Unfortunately, $\dim (\mathbf{f}) > \dim (\mathbf{x})$, so I can't just solve it as a system. So I have to do numeric optimization:

$$\mathbf{x}_{optimal}(\mathbf{a}) := \min_x ||\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{a})||$$
$$\mathbf{f}_{solved}(\mathbf{a}) := \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_{optimal}(\mathbf{a}), \mathbf{a})$$

Question is, how do I find jacobian of $\mathbf{f}_{solved}$? I remind that I don't have $\mathbf{x}_{optimal}$ at hand: I can only get solutions using numeric optimization.

Edit: Essentially, I'm trying to optimize $\mathbf{f}$ for $\mathbf{x}$ and then for $\mathbf{a}$, but I need to do it separately.

Comment: Any obstacles to using the Chain Rule and approximating the gradients arising in it by finite differences?

Comment: @avs Ok, I'll do that. But this will require $2 \dim(a)$ numeric optimizations per jacobian, which is unfortunate.

Comment: I can't think of any alternatives: as you specified, the function in question is unavailable.  Is there any additional information about ${\bf f}$ that can perhaps be used here?

Comment: @avs I can approximate it to second degree by $\mathbf{a}$ and still get usable solution. But not by $\mathbf{x}$.